# photoshop cs5 export layers to files issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, png, export

Hey i dont ussually work with photoshop, but i have many layers that i need make as PNG. 
I run that script, uncheck "visible layers only". And what i see in output folder is very weird. Its total mess.
 In one png image are two layers, sometimes one layer repeats many times and so on... And it never outputs so many files as it should.

I have normal PSD file with ~30 layers and weights under 10MBs

What could be a problem and maybe there is some workaround ??

Comment: problem was that i had layer groups.

Comment: you might consider answering your question to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Even with groups, it works like a charm.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8060862/layersaver.rar

You need to unzip this and then go to File - scripts - browse and select the jsx file. Use given options to save your files.